# Benefits of @FindBy annotations

Tags: automated-testing, selenium2, selenium-webdriver

I have recently come across [@FindBy](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/FindBy.html) as a method of locating elements within webdriver.  What are the benefits or disadvantages of this approach compared with the to more common approach of using [findElement](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html)?

Below are examples of the two methods;

```
WebElement searchButton = driver.findElement(By.id("btnSearch"))

@FindBy(id = "btnSearch")
private WebElement searchButton;
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking they are the same, @FindBy might be more suitable for PageObject Pattern.

Have a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18436102/selenium-findby-vs-driver-findelement)

Answer (score 0):

By using the @FindBy you're pulling the initialization of the code out of dirty, clunky, visually ugly and potentially confusing code into nice neat annotations.

Also, your removing the WebDriver nearly completely from the object, again keeping it clean.

They do the same functionality practically though.

Makes maintaining the code far easier long term.